# How to copy specific text?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have hundreds of word files to work one at a time, and each one has a line like this (not at the same relative place):

> Proc. nº 0032545-15.2012.8.19.0053

I need a code that copy only the serial number, in this case `0032545-15.2012.8.19.0053`, then I can use it to paste later. It doesnt need to supress the dots.

The code I've tried copies the entire line, but I have to copy only from the zeros ahead.
After that, I need the cursor to go to a specific part of the file (in this case, one line up the `12.12.13`, but it wont! Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub Macrovolta2()
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Proc. nº "
        .Execute Forward:=True
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=25, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Copy
    End With

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "12.12.13"
        .Execute Forward:=True
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: try first with some **tips&tricks** from [this site](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record your macro. Atl T, M, R.

You may find the F8 functionality useful. Press F8 and the character you want to select up to.

So Search for Proc, press right arrow to get to beginning of number, then F8 and space will select to the next space (assuming there is one after the number), then Shift + left arrow to shrink the selection so the trailing space isn't selected.

Another way is to search for the number if it's a consistent format.

```
^#^#^#^#^#^#^#-^#^#.^#^#^#^#.^#.^#^#.^#^#^#^#
```

^# means any digit. The above finds your number.

Also Word's search option Use Wildcards turns on regular expressions. You can search and pull out substrings.

```
Proc. nº ([0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9].[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4})
```

To access just the number use \1 (refers to the first term in brackets ()). [0-9] means any number. {4} means 4 of the previous character.